# Manipulate (crop and scale) the frame image in the analysis of the CameraX before display

Tags: android, image, processing, crop, android-camerax

I have an implementation of the CameraX and want to crop and scale each frame before I hand it out to the textureview to display.

```
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/view_finder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

MainActicity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);
        startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
}

 private void startCamera() {

    CameraX.unbindAll();

    Rational aspectRatio = new Rational (textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
    Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen


    PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                                .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                                .setTargetResolution(screen)
                                .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
                                .build();
    Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
            new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(textureView);
                    parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                    textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                    updateTransform();
                }
            });

    ImageAnalysis imageAnalyzer = this.buildImageAnalysisUseCase(aspectRatio,screen);

    final Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.bottom = 100;
    rect.right = 100;
    rect.left = 0;

    imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
        @Override
        public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
            Log.v("Analiiiize",rect.toString());
             image.setCropRect(rect); // here I hoped it will be cropped with a square of 100x100px in the top left corner and then displayed.. How could I achieve this here for each frame? 
            
            image.close();
        }
    });

    ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT).setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

    findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Pic captured at " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Pic capture failed : " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null){
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //bind to lifecycle:
    //CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, preview, imgCap);
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageAnalyzer);

}

private ImageAnalysis buildImageAnalysisUseCase(Rational aspectRatio,Size screen)

{
    ImageAnalysisConfig aConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
                                .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                                .setTargetResolution(screen)
                                .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
                                .build();
    ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(aConfig);
    return  analysis;
}

private void updateTransform(){
    Log.d("Was", "Uödate!");
    Matrix mx = new Matrix();
    float w = textureView.getMeasuredWidth();
    float h = textureView.getMeasuredHeight();

    float cX = w / 2f;
    float cY = h / 2f;

    int rotationDgr;
    int rotation = (int)textureView.getRotation();

    switch(rotation){
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            rotationDgr = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            rotationDgr = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            rotationDgr = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            rotationDgr = 270;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, cX, cY);
    textureView.setTransform(mx);
}
```

The reason I want to crop it in the analizer for each frame is that the cropping window could be changed from outside - in the beginning (0,0,100,100) and some seconds later for example (200,140,300,240)...

Comment: Could you describe your scenario to help me understand why do you want the crop rect to move like that?

Comment: @Xi 张熹 finally a developer from asia :) I know that you guys are very strong in [video processing](https://download.atlantis-press.com/article/25840614.pdf). What I am trying to do is: Step1: Use livestream of Camera for Face Detection => Get the position and boudary of the Mouth (x,y,width,height) and only preview this in "realtime"

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. :) However transforming the output in this case, is not trivial. You need something like Matrix#setPolyToPoly to match from the source to destination. In your case, the source is the mouth area, and the destination is the entire Preview surface. Note that there are other things need to consider. Please take a look at the source code of  PreviewView especiall this part: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/PreviewTransformation.java

Comment: what I see is that setPolyToPoly does some skewing? If you go to MLKit, in section [Landmarks](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/face-detection-concepts#landmarks) you see that MLKit gives me also a boundary box. So I don't need in the first step to deskew, but just zoom/scale + crop. But I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You don't need skew, but you would need rotation, which is why setPolyToPoly() is helpful. Transforming preview is a complicated matter. It will take a lot of work even if you are familiar with the topic. To get start with, I would suggest you take a look at the source code I posted above. CameraX might add features in the future to help with this scenario, but there is no ETA as of now.